# Fetch error on Google Colab folder: authuser=0: 405

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I'm currently using this code: https://github.com/NVlabs/MUNIT on a VM in GoogleColab Notebook.

I'm trying to figured out why the saving step isn't working, the only int I got is that when I tried to delete the checkpoints folder (the one used in the save action) this error is displayed:

`FetchError: Could not fetch resource at https://colab.research.google.com/tun/m/gpu-t4-s-3elyov2z1vt7c/api/contents/content/outputs/WebCaricature_front_warped/checkpoints?authuser=0: 405`

Now I'm trying to understand why and how to change that "authuser", I think the problem with the save step is about that particular folder's permissions.

Comment: Seems the saving steps works, pythorch.save generate the .pt file, but I can't see and access them in the google colab notebook.. (the error displayed seems to be connect to the fact that the folder isn't empty, it look like it's empty but if i do: !ls -l /checkpoints  I can see the .pt files